# Uninitialized Constant error (inside helper folder) after upgrading to Ruby 2.2.3 with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-2.2

I just upgraded from Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.2.3 using RVM and started getting the following output when I attempt to run `rails server`:

```
/Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant Platform::AddressesHelper (NameError)
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/actionpack-3.2.22/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:136:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/actionpack-3.2.22/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `map!'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/actionpack-3.2.22/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `modules_for_helpers'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:92:in `modules_for_helpers'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/actionpack-3.2.22/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:95:in `helper'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in with'
from /Users/nathalia/workspace/my_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nathalia/workspace/my_app/app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nathalia/workspace/my_app/app/controllers/admin/aee_activities_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:444:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:443:in `each'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:443:in `block in eager_load!'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:441:in `each'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:441:in `eager_load!'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/nathalia/workspace/my_app/config/initializers/paper_trail_ext.rb:86:in `<module:PaperTrail>'
from /Users/nathalia/workspace/my_app/config/initializers/paper_trail_ext.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `each'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/nathalia/workspace/my_app/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/nathalia/workspace/my_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /Users/nathalia/workspace/my_app/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/nathalia/workspace/my_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

This error seems to happen only within the folder "helpers/platform". I thought this might be an issue with the module being under a namespace but I have other modules that are inside the helpers folder and work under a namespace that don't show the same error.

I am not sure if this is related to some configuration missing or maybe incompatibility with some of my gems. I don't know exactly how to proceed from this so maybe someone can help me to figure where should I be looking at? Do I need to provide more information?

I'm using:

- Ruby 2.2.3
- Rails 3.2.22
- OS X Yosemite 10.10.4

Update - output for rvm info:

```
   ruby-2.2.3@my_app:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin Embu.local 14.4.0 Darwin Kernel 
    Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT 2015; 
    root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.10/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release 
    (x86_64-apple-darwin14)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, 
    Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "22 hours 26 minutes 56 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/nathalia/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.2.3p173"
    date:         "2015-08-18"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin14"
    patchlevel:   "2015-08-18 revision 51636"
    full_version: "ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) 
    [x86_64-darwin14]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app"
    ruby:         "/Users/nathalia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/nathalia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/nathalia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/nathalia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app/bin:/Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin:/Users/nathalia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/Users/nathalia/.rvm/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_app:/Users/nathalia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/nathalia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/nathalia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "my_app"
```

Comment: Append the output of `rvm info` to your question and format it for readability. I doubt it's an RVM problem though. It's more likely that the emitted code for your Rails project isn't current and needs to be.

Comment: have you upgraded Rails, or the other gems also?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I did upgrade several gems and also upgraded Rails from 3.2.17 to 3.2.22. This is a diff between my Gemfile.lock before and after the upgrade: https://www.diffchecker.com/kzcae1pz

Comment: @theTinMan I don't think it's a problem with RVM either but I couldn't find what might be wrong with my code yet. According to what I checked most code working under Ruby 1.9.3 should still work on 2.2.

Comment: Try to downgrade all the gems to prev version of Gemfile, it seems the problem is after the `bundle upgrade`

Comment: My main idea is to upgrade my app to have the latest versions of Rails and Ruby. So instead of downgrading I did the opposite and removed all specific versions (except Rails that I changed to 4.0.0) from my Gemfile and then ran bundle install. The error is gone and the only thing I have to do is correct all the changes due to upgrading the gems.
I don't know exactly what caused the issue with this settings but I guess it might be a incompatibility issue among some gems. If I find a specific answer I will post here!

Comment: Just for the record: before the bundle update I tried to upgrade only the paper_trail gem and then require it on config/application.rb but the error persisted. At this point I thought it might be an issue with paper_trail config but it looks like it wasn't.

Thank you so much for all your help! :)

Comment: Often it's not possible to downgrade gems beyond a certain point after upgrading the system because they might be taking advantage of new methods introduced by the upgrade.